# How to accelerate a C++ code using CUDA

Tags: cuda

I had done my physics simulation project using C++ , OpenGL in Visual Studio 10. Later I had used OpenMP for CPU Parallelization. Now I want to accelerate my C++ code to CUDA so that I can achieve  higher performance. Is it possible to convert my code into CUDA or any GPU devices?

Answer (score 2):

Cuda and C++ are different programming languages (even if they look syntactically similar) with different programming paradigm.

You'll have to recode, and perhaps even redesign, your project to take advantage of Cuda (or of OpenCL).

Actually, you'll need to define what are the numerical kernels that might take advantage of your GPGPU and then recode these kernels (in Cuda, or in OpenCL); you'll also have to write some glue code to make all this work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which parts of your project can be parallelized and then reimplement these parts in Cuda. You can take a look at [Fast N-Body Simulation with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch31.html).